# kivy capture mouse coordinates outside of window

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

How can I capture the mouse coordinates using Kivy when the mouse ventures outside the `Window` bounding box? I am creating a Desktop application.

Comment: with kivy you can not do it, that depends on each OS, so I recommend you point out that OS you have and look for libraries that implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `from kivy.utils import platform` to get the `platform` the app is being run on. Then, for windows:

`flags, hcursor, (x,y) = win32gui.GetCursorInfo()`

for Linux distros, use:

```
from Xlib import display
data = display.Display().screen().root.query_pointer()._data
data["root_x"], data["root_y"]
```

Comment: Thank you! I got to try a similar solution but this is better because it's general. Do you know why Kivy's Window.left/top and Window.size are inconsistent with actual pixel measurements on the screen? Until I reconcile this discrepancy, I am not able to make good use of your helpful answer here.